# Does the sequence converge on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, lebesgue-measure, almost-everywhere

Does the sequence $f_n(x) = \sin^n(x) + \cos^n(x)$ converge on $\mathbb{R}$?

a) almost everywhere

b) according to Lebesgue measure

**My solution:**

a) $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\sin^n(x) + \cos^n(x)) = 0$ (almost everywhere)

Therefore yes

b) $\lim \mu ${$ x: |\sin^n(x) + \cos^n(x)| \geq \varepsilon $}

and I don’t know what to do next, please push me to a solution

Thanks!

Comment: Is it true that $\forall\varepsilon>0,\forall n>0,\mu\{x\in[0,2\pi)\,:\, \lvert \sin^nx+\cos^nx\rvert\ge\varepsilon\}>0$ ?

Comment: Hint: For fixed $n$, let $E=\{x\in\mathbb{R}|\ |f_n(x)|>\epsilon\}$. Then $m(E)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}m(E\cap(0,2\pi])$. What can you say about $m(E\cap(0,2\pi])$? (Consider a left neighbourhood $(0,\delta)$ of $0$).

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio To be honest, it's not very obvious to me, can you please explain?

Comment: Since it seems you are new to measure theory, it is never too rigorous for you to consider anything. Here is another detail you might need to verify: Note the problem asks if $f_n$ converges in measure, and it didn't mention "to which". Therefore, it is also required to prove that besides $f\equiv 0$ (that is a spoiler, $f_n$ does not converge to $f\equiv 0$ in measure), $f_n$ can neither converge to other measurable functions, say, for instance, $g(x)=\chi_{\text{the fat Cantor set}}$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $\{f_n\}$ does not converge in measure. First we show that if $\psi$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}$ that is not [zero almost everywhere], then $f_n\not\to\psi$ in measure.
Next we show $f_n\not\to\psi$ in measure neither if $\psi\equiv 0$ a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Claim: If $\psi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty,-\infty\}$ is not [zero almost everywhere], then $f_n\not\to\psi$ in measure.

In fact, assume $f_n\to\psi$ in measure, and denote the constant zero function by $f$ (i.e. $f\equiv0\ \forall x$).
Then Riesz's theorem says exists a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ s.t. $f_{n_k}\to \psi$ a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
Since $f_n\to f$ a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}$, a fortiori we have $f_{n_k}\to f$ a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
Since $f_{n_k}$ converges both to $\psi$ and $f$ almost everywhere, we infer $\psi=f$ a.e,
that is $\psi\equiv 0$ a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}$, contradicting the hypothesis that $\psi$ is not [zero almost everywhere].
Therefore $f_n\not\to\psi$ in measure. We have verified our first claim.

Claim: If $\psi\equiv 0$ a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then neither does $\{f_n\}$ converges to $\psi$ in measure.

In fact, select a fixed $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$.
Since $f_n(0)=1$,
therefore by continuity, given any $\epsilon\in (0,1)$, exists $d\in (0,2\pi)$ s.t. $|f_n(x)|>\epsilon$ for all $x\in(0,d)$,
i.e.
\begin{equation}
\{x\in (0,2\pi):\ |f_n(x)|>\epsilon\}\supseteq (0,d) .
\end{equation}
Hence for all  $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, for all $\epsilon\in (0,1)$,
\begin{equation}
m(\{x\in (0,2\pi):\ |f_n(x)|>\epsilon\})>d>0.
\end{equation}
Therefore
\begin{equation}
m(\{x\in \mathbb{R}:\ |f_n(x)|>\epsilon\})=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_n=+\infty,
\end{equation}
where $a_n\equiv m(\{x\in (0,2\pi):\ |f_n(x)|>\epsilon\})\ \forall n $ is a constant positive sequence.
Therefore $\{f_n\}$ does not converge to $\psi\equiv 0\ (\forall x\in\mathbb{R})$ in measure, giving pur second claim.

To sum up, for all measurable function $\psi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty,-\infty\}$, $\{f_n\}$ does not converge to $\psi\equiv 0\ (\forall x\in\mathbb{R})$ in measure.